# I keep calculating a Lagrange error bound that is lesser than the actual error's absolute value. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider the function f(x)=sin(x) evaluated at x=.4. If you use a degree-one (i.e., n=1) Maclaurin polynomial, P(x), to approximate the function, you get an actual error equal to f(.4)-P(.4), or sin(.4)-.4, which means that the absolute value of the error is roughly .3930.

However, when you calculate the maximum absolute value of the (n+1)th derivative of f(x) over [0,.4], which is sin(.4), you cannot use this value as M to calculate the Lagrange error bound. If you try to, you get M(/x-0/^(n+1)) divided by (n+1)!, or (sin.4)(.4^2)/2!, which is approximately .0005585, a value less than the actual error.

How is it possible to get a Lagrange error bound value lesser than the actual error's absolute value? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think you're mixing radians and degrees.

Comment: I calculated everything using degrees. But it shouldn't matter whether everything is calculated in degrees or everything is calculated in radians, right?

Comment: @resplaine Yes, it makes a big difference.   $x$ is always in radians in the formulas.

Comment: Thanks. I calculated it again in radians, and everything is now hunky-dory. (Didn't realize how the formulas were derived).

Answer (score 1):

> I calculated everything using degrees. But it shouldn't matter whether everything is calculated in degrees or everything is calculated in radians, right?

The calculus of trigonometric functions is always in radians. It's the entire point of using radians; we might as well use degrees for everything else, but as soon as a derivative or an integral is involved, it's time to use radians.

The derivative formula $\frac{d}{dx}\sin x=\cos x$? That relies on radians, as do all the other derivative formulas. If we tried to differentiate $\sin_\circ$, the sine of an angle expressed in degrees, we would get a constant multiple: $\sin_\circ(x)=\sin(\frac{\pi}{180}x)$, so
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin_\circ(x)=\frac{\pi}{180}\cos(\frac{\pi}{180}x)=\frac{\pi}{180}\cos_\circ(x)$$
Repeat that, and we multiply by another $\frac{\pi}{180}$ for each derivative. That's going to seriously throw off a power series.

So, instead, we do all of our calculus with radians - the measure chosen to make that constant multiple in the derivatives just $1$.